# Objective - C Get all file in google driver API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to get all file (object data GTLRDrive_File) in my folder with folderId.
ex i have a folder PAT in folder have folder_1, folder_2, folder_3,....
in folder 1 2 3 i have folder_1_1, folder_1_2, folder_2_1,.....
[image]

Now i want get all item in folder. I try write code but it not working. this code is link : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios

Answer (score 0):

To get all file in google drive api, use [File.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list). It will return everything including items inside folders.